# Clear Instructions on Adding Javascript to Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I looked for a very long time to try to understand this. How can I add Javascript to Selenium IDE? I've been recording a test case and can only get to a certain point without adding scripts. (I'm trying to click on a link that is part of a frame and it's very difficult without using window.switchTo(frameName);, which needs to be included in scripts).

Where do I add the scripts? How? Please include clear instructions and links if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You want the "runScript" command.

Example here: [CLICKY ...](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/selenium-ide-runscript-command-example.html)